# When image are more than 6 I need a line break , how can I can do that?

Tags: php, mysql

When image are more than 6 I need a line break.

```
       while($row  = mysql_fetch_array($q))
      {
         echo "<img src=\"$row[image_link]\" />";
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `mysql_num_rows()`

```
$cnt = mysql_num_rows($q);
if($cnt>6)
{
   echo "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well you already had your answer so I'm just here to say that alternatively you can use in your images `style="float: left"`.

This will make them automatically break line *when it is needed* depending on the screen size instead of always doing it every 6 images.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    $i = 0;
    while($row  = mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {
        if ($i%6 == 0 && $i != 0)
        {
                echo "<br/>";
        }
        echo "<img src=\"$row[image_link]\" />";
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count=1;
while($row  = mysql_fetch_array($q))
      {
         if($count%6==0) 
         echo "<br/>";
         echo "<img src=\"$row[image_link]\" />";
         $count++;

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $count =0;
         while($row  = mysql_fetch_array($q))
              {
                 echo "<img src=\"$row[image_link]\" />";
                  $count++;
                   if($count>=6)
                     {
                     echo "</br>";
                     $count=0;
                     }                

              }
```

Answer (score 0):

not good but try this if you want:

```
 $i = "1";
 while($row  = mysql_fetch_array($q))
  {
     echo "<img src=\"$row[image_link]\" />";
     if($i == 6){ echo "<br>";}
     $i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
    $i=1;
    while($row  = mysql_fetch_array($q))
      {

         echo "<img src=\"$row[image_link]\" />";

          if(($i%6)==0){ 
                echo "<hr/>";
          }
         $i++;

      }
```